# Refer to the main form from child form

Tags: c#, .net

I have a main form and that open a child:

```
Preeee p = new Preeee();
p.MdiParent = this;
p.Show();
```

and in certain point the child form will closes and opens it self:

```
Preeee p = new Preeee();
p.MdiParent = this;
p.Show();
this.Close();
```

but of course `this` in the second line refer to itself but i want it to refer to another form witch is the main form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just want to pass the parent along, which you can do like this:

```
p.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
```